Displaying pdf file on php webpage not visible on iPad or iPhone, but shows on computer browsers
I have a set of webpages that display pdf file pages using a php display page. Everything works on computer browsers, but on tablets (iPad) and phones the page loads but does not display the pdf. The line of code that displays the pdf looks like this:
echo '<object data="pdf/' . $fn . '.pdf" width="1000px" height="1300px"></object>';

The $fn variable is passed via a cookie from one page to the next. There doesn't seem to be anything else wrong with the page, leaving me to wonder if the problem is an issue with the object tag, but I don't understand why.
This can be viewed from the page at https://bullittcountyhistory.org/bcgensoc/wr/a.html if you select one of the links like the 4-61 link for William Aban (or any other one as well).
Any help will be appreciated.
Follow-up 3 May 2024. Concluded that the best way to present these pdf pages on small screens was to provide a link to display the page as a pdf file instead of a html file. The main reason why we want to display the pdf page on a html page is that we have the names indexed and need to provide links to them as you may see on the front page at https://bullittcountyhistory.org/bcgensoc/wr/index.html
